# JDBI query fails when <> is used

Tags: java, postgresql, dropwizard, jdbi

I have a JDBI query that is as simple as it can be

```
@Override
@SqlQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE (" + COLUMN_MODERATOR_CATEGORY_ID
                + " in (<categories>) OR " + COLUMN_EXPERT_CATEGORY_ID
                + " in (<categories>)) AND (" + COLUMN_STATUS + " <> 0)")
long getIdeasCountInCategories(@BindIn("categories") List<Long> categories);
```

The `<> 0` fails with a `syntax error at the end of input...`. It works as soon as I change it to `> 0` (which also serves the purpose).

Using Java 1.8.0 and Postgres 9.6. Please let me know if any more info is needed.

Comment: Please post exact error message.

Comment: Done @talex. Trust me, rest of it is unhelpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely can't change the SQL query (e.g. switch operator to `!=` or `>`) then you need to escape `<` with preceding `\\`.

Comment: Thanks, I realize it makes more sense to use `!=`.